# Asp.net resources - prevent error on page when resource reference is invalid

Tags: asp.net, resources, dynamic

I'm using resources like this;
  " runat="server" />

Resources are maintained in a database and resourcefiles are generated when new translations are added. Sometimes bad references to keys happens. This results in error on the whole page.

How can I prevent the whole page from crashing when a resource does not exist? I just want a tiny error message where the resource lacks, like "Not found: Users.DetailsUserHeadline".

I also want to dynamically retrieve resources from code behind, by defining the key as a string "Users.DetailsUserHeadline" without any erros.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use the ResourceKey instead if the resource is not found**, just modify the method which is used to get the resource. It should look like:

```
public class ResourceManager
{
   public static string GetResource(string key)
   {
      string val = TryGet(key);
      if (string.IsNullorEmpty(val)) val = key;
      return val;
      //or you don't use a TryGet method
      //try
      //{
      //   val = GetTheResource(key);
      //}
      //catch (ResourceNotFoundException e)
      //{
      //   val = key;
      //}
   }
}
```

**If you want to show a prompt that the resource is not found to users**, you need to write your own exception like:

```
public class ResourceNotFoundException : Exception
{
   // define the properties you want to get
}
```

And use `throw new ResourceNotFoundException()` when you try to get the resource. In your UI part you can catch the exception and show something to users.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!  I can't find a ResourceManager in my project (someone else created the resource part in the project), can it be that the project uses a standard implementation of Resource usage? Can I override this somehow?